# Pandas Dataframe: Groupby on first two columns and count the occurence for first column

Tags: pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby, aggregate

I had a dataset as a result of groupby as :

CUSTID  TRANSACTION_ID    COUNT

```
CU_1    TR_1                1  
CU_1    TR_2                1
CU_1    TR_3                1
CU_2    TR_4                1  
CU_2    TR_5                1
```

I needed to have result as
CUSTID  TOTAL_COUNT

```
CU_1       3          
CU_2       2
```

Comment: What have you tried? Did you groupby the first columns and simply take the count of the second column?

Comment: `df = df.groupby(['c1'])['c2'].count().reset_index()`

Comment: Thanks David @DavidErickson that did the job for me !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Run just:

```
df.groupby('CUSTID').COUNT.sum()
```

You need to group by a **single** column (*CUSTID*) only, then,
from each group, take *COUNT* column and compute its *sum()*.

Additional step may be to provide the required name to the resulting
*Series*. If it is important, append `.rename('TOTAL_COUNT')`
to the above code.

Yet another step may be to convert this *Series* into a *DataFrame*.
To do it, append `.to_frame()` to the above code.

Comment: Thanks for the help @Valdi_Bo , I was able to get through with the step David mentioned above .